Representation of Dirac-delta distribution in subspace of functions
Suppose I have a subspace $V\subset L^2(\Omega)$ where $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^d$ is a bounded and closed set. $V$ is defined by
\begin{align}
V=\text{span}(\{\varphi_i(x): i=1,2,\dots,n\}) 
\end{align}
where $\varphi_i\in L^2(\Omega)$ are linearly independent continuous and non-negative functions.

Edit:
The specific functions I'm interested in are $\varphi_i(x)=\text{max}(\hat{n}_i\cdot x+t_i,0)$ where $\hat{n}_i$ are different unit vectors and $t_i$ are different scalars.

Let $w\in V$ be a function with the property that:
\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega}\varphi_i(x)w(x)dx=\varphi_i(x^*),\quad \text{for all }i=1,...,n
\end{align}
where $x^*\in \Omega$. Thus, $w$ act on functions in $V$ like the dirac-delta function $\delta(x-x^*)$. However, $w\neq \delta(x-x^*)$ since $\delta(x-x^*)\notin V$.
Since $w\in V$ we have that $w=\sum_{i=1}^nc_i\varphi_i(x)$ for some coefficient $c_i$. To find the coefficient, we just define the $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix $K$ with elements:
\begin{align}
[K]_{ij}=\int_{\Omega}\varphi_i(x)\varphi_j(x)dx
\end{align}
and the vector $\bar{\varphi}^*=[\varphi_i(x^*),\dots,\varphi_n(x^*)]^T$
Then it follows that the coefficient vector $\bar{c}=[c_1,\dots,c_n]^T$ is the solution to the linear system
\begin{align}
K\bar{c}=\bar{\varphi}^*
\end{align}
Question
I would like to show that $\|w\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}\leq C n$ for some constant $C$.
That is, the $L^2$-norm of the function $w$ with the property described above, scales as $n$ (the number of basis functions in $V$). From the definition of $w$ we also have for instance that $\|w\|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}=w(x^*)$.
Does anyone know how to go about this problem? Do we need to assume anything more about the basis functions $\varphi_i(x)$?
All ideas and suggestions are highly appreciated.

(i) What is $\bar{\varphi}^*$? (ii) More importantly, what do you mean, exactly, by "constant $C$"? Clearly, $C$ must depend on the family $(\varphi_i)_{i=1}^n$, of which $n$ is an attribute.

I don't think that that claim is true in general. I have in mind to take the $\phi_i$ as bumps localized at $i$ that get higher quickly and narrower even more quickly  forcing $w$ to be large there as well, but I haven't done the calculation.

@IosifPinelis I defined $\bar{\varphi}^$ as the vector with elements $\varphi_i(x^)$, $i=1,2,...,n$. The constant can depend on characteristics of the basis functions $\varphi_i$, i.e. the norm or something like that. The specific functions im interested in are:
$\varphi_i(x)=\text{max}(\hat{n}_i\cdot x+t_i,0)$ where $\hat{n}_i$ are unit vectors and $t_i$ are scalars.

It resembles the Bergman kernel function.

@Erling : Let me try to convey my point again: $n$ is a function of the family $(\varphi_i){i=1}^n$: If you know this family, then you know $n$. Also, $n$ is a function of the family $((\hat n_i,t_i)){i=1}^n$. So, if you only say that $C$ may depend on one of these two families, you allow $C$ to depend on $n$. So, then your request for a bound of the form $Cn$ is not meaningful, as you can then define the new "constant" $C_1$ as $Cn$.

What i mean is that if I  would compute $|w|^2_{L^2(\Omega)}$ for different values of $n$ and make a plot the values vs $n$ then I would get a straight line.

@Erling : You probably did this only for some specific $\varphi_i$'s, rather than in general. You cannot expect this to hold generally. Anyhow, you should specify the meaning of $C$, for the question to become meaningful.
